# How to use jq to parse and display specific variables

Tags: jq

I want to display specific variables of a data table.

```
` [
   {
     {
      "agent_installed" : true,
      "agent_version" : "",
      "asset_tag" : "",
      "blueprint_id" : "",
      "blueprint_name" : "",
      "device_id" : "d35feff4-7867-268a-zet1-82caa4bcf5a0",
      "device_name" : "Spare's MacBook Air",
      "model" : "MacBook Air",
      "os_version" : "13.3.1",
      "platform" : "Mac",
      "serial_number" : "FK1VXASVRFS2E",
      
      }
   }
]`
```

using this command `jq -r '.[] | "device_id=\(.device_id) os_version=\(.os_version)"'`
I'm able to display the device_id and the os version after, now what i'd like to know is this :

Is it possible with using jq to have a more specific return, for example i'd like to display only the device_id of the devices that have the 13.3.1 version.

Comment: Fix your JSON to show a valid one

Comment: `jq '.[] | select(.os_version == "13.3.1") | .device_id' yourfile.json`  Does this work ?

Answer (score 0):

The data presented are not well-formed JSON.  Based on the command you say works for you on your input, I guess you must have an array of objects, the objects directly containing the keys you want to display or use for filtering.  That is, something more like this:

```
[
   {
      "agent_installed" : true,
      "agent_version" : "",
      "asset_tag" : "",
      "blueprint_id" : "",
      "blueprint_name" : "",
      "device_id" : "d35feff4-7867-268a-zet1-82caa4bcf5a0",
      "device_name" : "Spare's MacBook Air",
      "model" : "MacBook Air",
      "os_version" : "13.3.1",
      "platform" : "Mac",
      "serial_number" : "FK1VXASVRFS2E"
   },

   ... other objects ...
]
```

> Is it possible with using jq to have a more specific return, for example i'd like to display only the device_id of the devices that have the 13.3.1 version.

I take you to be asking about selecting a subset of the array elements to report upon.  Yes, the [`select()`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#select) function provides this capability.  Inserting an appropriate `select()` will allow you to filter your array's elements to include only those satisfying a condition you specify.  For example, for input structured as shown above, this ...

```
jq '.[] | select(.os_version == "13.3.1") | .device_id' input_file
```

... will print a sequence of JSON strings containing the `device_id` values of the array elements having `os_version` of "13.3.1".